# How do I repair crumbling wall plaster?

Tags: repair, walls, plaster, lath-and-plaster

I found this in a closet behind something that a previous owner had nailed into a wall.  It's inside a closet, so it doesn't have to look pretty, I just don't want it to keep crumbling.  I was going to get some plaster adhesive and just fill it in.  Any other tips or ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had a lot of success in the past by using a mixture of PVA Glue and water and then painting the solution over the crumbling area. The glue gets absorbed into the crumbling surface and stabilises it. Then you can refinish with a thin coat of filler or plaster. It saves a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

You should first remove any loose debris before filling it.  I would also advise removing the wall paper around the area you are patching.  If you patch on top of the wallpaper,  when you go to remove it you will end up damaging that spot again.

You will likely need a few applications to completely fill an area of that size.